# Conflict \thead function defined in two packages

Tags: tables, incompatibility, makecell

I'm using both:

```
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablestyles}
```

in a *.tex document.

If I use the previously shown order, I got an `! LaTeX Error: Command \thead already defined.` error on the `tablestyles` package at line `120`:

```
\newcommand\thead{%
  \tablefontsize{head}
}
```

If I inverse the two requirement lines such as:

```
\usepackage{tablestyles}
\usepackage{makecell}
```

I got the same error as before but on the `makecell` package, line `34`:

```
\newcommand\thead{\@ifstar{\let\tabg@pe\gape\thead@}%
                          {\let\tabg@pe\theadgape\thead@}}
```

How could I make use of the two packages without conflicts and without having to touch to their definition styles?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. What would you use `makecell` for, exactly?

Comment: Hmm, I see. So there is no such comprehensive listing of *all* available functions names so that developers can see before developing a package which functions names are already used? Makecell is for adding line breaks in cells in my situation.

Comment: Yes it's strange, all the more so that makecell is a well-known package. For line breaks in standard cells (r, l,c) you can use the `\Centerstack`command (in text mode) or `\Vectorstack` (in math mode) commands from `stackengine`(to be loaded with option `[usestackEOL]` to get the usual typing for line breaks).